# g++ linker: /usr/lib/libGL.so.1: could not read symbols: Invalid operation

Tags: c++, opengl, linker, glut

I'm trying to build a very simple OpenGL-app under Ubuntu 10.04 (I have a 32 bit system).

When I'm trying to compile the file, I get the error message:

```
g++ -L/usr/lib simple.cpp -lglut
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccoPczAo.o: undefined reference to symbol 'glEnd'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'glEnd' is defined in DSO //usr/lib/libGL.so.1 so try adding it to the linker command line
//usr/lib/libGL.so.1: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Not really related to your question, but I see that you are using glEnd(), which is deprecated since GL3. If you are beginning OpenGL programming, I would suggest that you start out using GL3+ with the "core profile". Old OpenGL is not only slow, but also very limited.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to include the opengl library on the command line as well as the glut library/.
Try adding -lGL to the end of your command line

```
g++ -L/usr/lib simple.cpp -lglut -lGL
```

Comment: Thank you. It solved my problem partially, so I could do the rest (had to add `-lGLU` as well).

Comment: Anybody can explain why does it print 
`/usr/lib/libGL.so.1: could not read symbols: Invalid operation`?
This looks like it tries to read the missing library, but failing.

Answer (score 1):

compile with

```
g++ main.cpp -o main.bin -lGL -lGLU -lglut
```

or Try the following make file from [OpenGL primer](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~jstratto/opengl/) it is very compact.
This one helped me to run my Hello world OpenGL.
Thanks to [OpenGL Primer](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~jstratto/opengl/)

```
CC = g++
SRC = main.cpp imageloader.cpp
LIBS = -lGL -lGLU -lglut
EXEC = cube.bin

all:
       $(CC) $(SRC) -o $(EXEC) $(LIBS)

clean:
       rm -rf $(EXEC) *~
```